# SSRS group by with sum in expression

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I need to generate a calculated field with sum(Value1) and groupby(Value2) and use this this calculated field in the IIF condition to create other column.

I am trying to convert a SAP crystal report formula to SSRS

```
If Sum ({abc}, {123}) >0 then
{abc}/Sum ({abc}, {123}) *100
else 0
```

I need to do in SSRS.

Comment: what expressions have you tried that aren't working?

Answer (score 2):

the IIF syntax in SSRS is

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!abc.Value, "Group123") > 0, 
   Fields!abc.Value/SUM(Fields!abc.Value,"Group123") * 100, 
   0
)
```

The `"Group123"` value is the name of the group you want to use.

Comment: How could you possibly figure out the answer without knowing what didn't work? :p

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what output you want to get? If possible, could you please inform me more detailed information(such as your data sample and your expecting output)?

And if you want to get sum of a specific group, you could use expression like below
=sum(iif(Fields!group.Value="aa", Fields!abc.Value,0))

Zoe Zhi